# Buffer used for TcpClient gets overwritten before message could be read

Tags: c#, tcpclient

To send data over a TCP connection for an application of mine I use a simple piece of code:

```
public void Send(byte[] message)
{
    if (socket != null)
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            if (receiveThread == null)
            {
                StartReceiver();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The socket is an instance of the `TcpClient` class, and the stream is the associated stream instance. `StartReceiver()` starts a Thread which, as the method implies, receives data sent to the application.

To receive data, I use:

```
private void ReceiveLoop()
{
    DataReceivedStruct drs;
    try
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                drs = new DataReceivedStruct();
                drs.stream = stream;
                drs.waitHandle = are;
                stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, DataReceived, drs);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting to be allowed to continue");
                are.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Allowed, continuing loop");
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        DispatchRaiseException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DispatchRaiseException(e);
    }
}
```

Again, the stream used is the aforementioned stream instance of the `TcpClient` class object. The readBuffer object is a `byte[1024]`. The callback given to `BeginRead` looks like this:

```
private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{
    DataReceivedStruct drs = (DataReceivedStruct)result.AsyncState;
    NetworkStream used = drs.stream;
    AutoResetEvent handle = drs.waitHandle;
    used.EndRead(result);
    DispatchRaiseReceived(readBuffer);
    Console.WriteLine("Signalling allowance of continue for loop");
    handle.Set();
}
```

It ends the read action on the stream and passes on the data set in the readBuffer.

This works in principle. I can send and receive data from and to the application. There is only one issue with the receiving end of the application. When a message is sent to the application, the `BeginRead` function is called, after which the callback fires and ends the read operation with `EndRead` and passes on the data for further processing. This works for a single message at a time. But it gets more interesting when another message is sent directly after the first message triggered the `BeginRead`. What happens then is that the `EndRead` for the first message hasn't occurred yet, so the data of the first message is written over by the second message, resulting in incorrect data.

Should I stop using `BeginRead`/`EndRead` and just use a blocking `Read` operation to receive the data? Or is it possible to lock the stream with `BeginRead`/`EndRead` so the second message isn't received until the first message is handled?

Comment: instead of using a shared buffer(`readBuffer`), declare it in `DataReceivedStruct`

Comment: That wouldn't matter, because the stream would still overwrite it for the second message.

Comment: No, since you create a new `DataReceivedStruct` in your loop before passing it to `BeginRead`

Comment: D'oh... my bad... I misunderstood your solution.

Comment: I would accept this, as this answers my question, but a comment is not an answer... :<

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the problem here is thinking in terms of a loop, hence requiring a continue flag. That does not scale, as it requires a thread per connection.

What you *should* do is:

- get some data to send
- start receiving async (I use ReceiveAsync, but BeginRead should work too)
- and exit! (no loop)

In the callback:

- process the fragment (or buffer it)
- start receiving if necessary
- and exit!

If you are happy to alternate a few different buffers (I use a small micro-pool), you can swap the "process" so that you can continue reading in parallel to processing. But then you absolutely need different buffers each read, to prevent over-writing the data. This is only usually necessary for **exceptionally** high read scenarios.

If it helps, I am working on a library for writing simple TCP client/server scenarios without having to worry about all the grungy implementation details, that I plan on releasing as open-source once stable; featuring extensive object pooling/re-use, totally async usage (with the 3.5 API that binds to completion-ports), etc.

Comment: I know it is kind of a lazy way of doing things with the loop, but I was not aiming to go to deep into the whole issue due to time limitations. Hearing about your library is interesting, but not an option to look into as of now, obviously. Anyway, thanks for the interesting alternative.

Comment: On another note, I actually designed it like this because my application can have multiple TCP connections to other instances, hence the need of a thread per connection. If it were UDP, I could see your suggestion work.

Comment: @ThaMe90 not sure why that needs a thread. For example, the thing I'm working on at the moment; have tested it with 25k inbound connections, with each client-side talking to several servers in a group (load-balancing client between servers), and each server servicing multiple TCP bindings; number of threads I explicitly spin up: zero.

Comment: Now that I rethink my approach, I don't see why that would need a thread as well, as long as the async messages are used. But besides that, I think this goes beyond my issue. My issue is that my data get's overwritten by the second message before the first is handled.

Comment: @ThaMe90 as long as you don't call the next BeginRead until you are done with the data, there is no risk over overlap; the key is: either process it **before** calling BeginRead, or swap the buffers, and use a different buffer for the next BeginRead while you process the first.

Comment: @ThaMe90 if the processing in `DispatchRaiseReceived(readBuffer);` is happening on a different thread, then yes: don't do that ;p You need to read **after** it has been processed, or: use a different buffer

Comment: I did that, as L.B. brought that up via the comments above. I moved the buffer to the data struct, and create a new buffer for each `BeginRead` call. It now works as expected. Though given, I should refactor this piece of code.